# Implementing functional programming concepts in data analysis with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, immutability

I am learning functional programming to improve my data analysis pipeline. In particular, the idea of pure functions where functions have no side effects is very useful. Also, the concept of immutable data is nice for data processing. However, I am not very sure about how to implement the concept with pandas data frames especially when we have large dataframes that we don't want to keep making copies of.

I read something about persistent data structures, but I am not sure whether it could be implemented with pandas

```py
# Suppose we have some large dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(some_huge_data, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])

# We want to process the data, say adding modify a column and then two columns together 
def process_df(df_inside_func):
    df_inside_func = \
    (df_insidefunc
    .assign(column1=lambda x: x.column1 + 2)
    .assign(new_column=lambda x: x.column1 + x.column2)
    )
    return df_inside_func

# In my normal workflow
df = process_df(df)

# However in FP, I believe I should assign the output to a new variable, but the memory would double. 
df_processed = process_df(df)
```

My current imperfect solution: keep existing columns immutable and make new column whenever column modification is implemented

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(some_huge_data, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])


def process_df(df_inside_func):
    try:
        df_inside_func = df_inside_func[['column1', 'column2']]
    except:
        raise
    
    df_inside_func = \
    (df_insidefunc
    .assign(modified_column1 = lambda x: x.column1 + 2)
    .assign(new_column=lambda x: x.modified_column1 + x.column 2)
    )
    return df_inside_func

df = process_df(df)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on a better implementation? Many thanks in advance

Comment: `df_processed = process_df(df)` is not pure, you will mutate the original `df` unless you explicitly make a copy inside the function.  You can verify this with `id(df_processed) == id(df)`

Comment: on a practical note, I think you're better off with one of two paths: 1) setting the expectation that functions do not modify input (you can use `df_inside_func = df.copy()` at the top of the function) at the expense of memory consumption, or 2) accept that they do, *caveat emptor* to function caller.